# What does 'welcome below' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> With apologies to the CBC radio program This is That, which was likely
>   planning a segment of its own on this important topic, reader comments
>   on the idea of having Britain become part of Canada are **welcome
>   below**.

[A modest proposal for the U.K. as it eyes NAFTA](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/nafta-britain-canada-1.4353341)

What does '**welcome below**' mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments section appears lower on the page than the quote you've provided. I think that, if you exclude part of the sentence, it will make more sense:

> . . . reader comments [. . .] are welcome below.

And here's what it looks like:

[image: Comments section on linked page with quoted text]
(click to expand)

So, I might similarly say "Comments on this answer are welcome below" meaning, "feel free to post a comment about what you think of this answer in the space provided, which is below this post".

Comment: oh! I've got it. --;;